# How to map div id to a 2d array position

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Is it possible to map `div id = "div1"` to `array[0][0]` , `div id = "div2"` to `array[0][1]` and so on? Also can a value be user inputted and be stored at  `array[0][0]` and `array[0][1]` thus corresponding to div1 and div2? Thanks

```
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
```

equates to

```
Array[0][0] =
```

An image is dropped in the location where div id = div1 A combo box is then used (user input) where a value of 1 is selected and goes into the array [0][0] location thus showing 1. Same is done in div 2 giving value 5 into array [0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCu0t.png) location. Can this be done?

[Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCu0t.png)

Comment: please add some examples of the wanted result

Comment: need more details about it

Comment: An image is dropped in the location where div id = div1 A combo box is then used (user input) where a value of 1 is selected and goes into the array [0][0] location thus showing 1. Same is done in div 2 giving value 5 into array [0][1] location. Can this be done?